# Adding an intent to a TabActivity in Android

Tags: android, image, layout, android-tabactivity

I checked up some online tutorials on how to build a TAB in android and saw a tutorial that fit my requirements. I was happy to implement it and it worked well. The problem came when I wanted each separate tab to push to one separate activity. I couldn't start and intent to pass on the control. I've given only the main code as to how I am making the Tab's as the xml required for the construction does not have any functionality in this question.

Here is the code:

```
public class Secondactivity extends TabActivity {
private TabHost mTabHost;
private void setupTabHost() {
mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setupTabHost();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(se.copernicus.activity.R.drawable.tab_divider);

    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Month");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Week");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Day");
}
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview)
        .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return view;
            }
        });
mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
tv.setText(text);
return view;
   }
}
```

How can I start a new Intent so that when the Tab is clicked it should go from `Secondactivity` to `WeekActivity` or `DayActivity` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity

{
    private TabHost mTabHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.program_guide_tab_activity_layout);

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.live));
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.guide));
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.remotes));
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.settings));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(getString(R.string.live));
}

private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag)
{
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

    if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.live)) == 0)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LiveActivity.class);

        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.live)).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
        {

            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                return view;
            }

        });

        setContent.setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }

    if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.guide)) == 0)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProgramGuide.class);

        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.guide)).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
        {

            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                return view;
            }

        });

        setContent.setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }

    if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.remotes)) == 0)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RemoteMultiPanel.class);

        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.remotes)).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
        {

            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                return view;
            }

        });

        setContent.setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }

    if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.settings)) == 0)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsMain.class);

        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.settings)).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
        {

            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                return view;
            }

        });

        setContent.setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);

    int resId = 0;
    ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    if (text.compareTo(context.getString(R.string.settings)) == 0)
    {
        resId = R.drawable.settings_icon;
    }
    else if (text.compareTo(context.getString(R.string.remotes)) == 0)
    {
        resId = R.drawable.remotes_icon;
    }
    else if (text.compareTo(context.getString(R.string.live)) == 0)
    {
        resId = R.drawable.live_icon;
    }
    else if (text.compareTo(context.getString(R.string.guide)) == 0)
    {
        resId = R.drawable.guide_icon;
    }

    iconImageView.setImageResource(resId);

    return view;
}
```

}

check out the setupTap() method:
it's control the 4 possible intent's that raised activities:
LiveActivity, ProgramGuide, ....

Comment: tell me if it helped, or if you need any other help

Comment: don't forget to mark it as "solved" if it really helped you :)

Comment: @TalKanel Will the activity cause "ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut" Since the oncreate activity is overburdened.