# How to clear the Child activities on clicking the particular tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I want to know how to clear child activities and how to invoke the parent activity of a particular tab on its second click (tab functionality like on iPhone?). I want to invoke the click listener for each tab. Assume as if the application gets deeper while using, it's hard to use the back button often to reach the parent activity. So i need to invoke the parent activity by clicking the tab.

On first tab it is working fine, here is the code

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {      
        if (getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("gebrauchte")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TabHome.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else{                 
            tabs.setCurrentTab(0);  
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to use the same code for the second tab with getChildAt(1), should i give TabHome class for all intent, if I try to give their respective class of 2nd, 3rd and 4th tab, the tabHost gets hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set onClickListener on Tabs. I would advice to use [Android Tabs with Fragments](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/)

Comment: Thank you for reply, Is there any possibility without using fragments. Because, if I go through the fragments, i need to edit number of classes.

Comment: there is a tabHost for this purposes, and early developers used activities for every tab. But now it's deprecated and de f acto this is bad idea. But you can use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243078/adding-an-intent-to-a-tabactivity-in-android. But I enforce you to use Fragments :)